# dispatch of connect doesn't work in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

native`using`react-redux`,`react-thunk`,`handleActions`with`ducks structure` and trying to dispatch action function to change state.

It worked actually until this morning, but it doesn't work anymore.
I have no idea what I changed. Even worse, I didn't commit because this project is for practicing react native, so I cannot undo my work.

If I'm right that I understood correctly, `dispatch` of `connect` in container component should call `fetchName()` in `categoryImgListMod.js(action)`.

However, I guess `dispatch` never works here.
So state never changes.

If you give me any of advice, it would be very helpful for me, and I would appreciate you.

Here's my code

---

**categoryListContainer.js**

```jsx
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CategoryImgList from '../components/categoryImgList';

import * as CategoryImgActions from '../store/modules/categoryImgListMod';

class CategoryImgListContainer extends Component {
  loadNames = async () => {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { CategoryImgActions } = this.props;
    try {
        await CategoryImgActions.fetchName();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

render() {
    const {container} = styles;
    const { loadNames } = this;

    return (
        <View style={container}>
            <CategoryImgList names={loadNames}/>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    height: '100%'
  }
}

export default connect(
  ({categoryImgListMod}) => ({
    name: categoryImgListMod.name
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    fetchName: () => {
        dispatch(CategoryImgActions.fetchName())
    }
  })
)(CategoryImgListContainer);
```

---

**categoryImgListMod.js**

```jsx
import {handleActions} from 'redux-actions';

// firestore
import * as db from '../../shared';

// Action types
const GET_CATEGORY_NAME_PENDING = 'categoryImgList/GET_CATEGORY_NAME_PENDING';
const GET_CATEGORY_NAME_SUCCESS = 'categoryImgList/GET_CATEGORY_NAME_SUCCESS';
const GET_CATEGORY_NAME_FAILURE = 'categoryImgList/GET_CATEGORY_NAME_FAILURE';

// action creator
export const fetchName = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({type: GET_CATEGORY_NAME_PENDING});
  try {
    const response = await db.getCategoryNames();

    const arr = [];
    response.docs.forEach(res => {
        arr.push(res.id);
    });

    dispatch({type: GET_CATEGORY_NAME_SUCCESS, payload: arr});
    return arr;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    dispatch({type: GET_CATEGORY_NAME_FAILURE, payload: e});
  }
}

const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  error: false,
  name: []
};

// Reducer
export default handleActions({
  [GET_CATEGORY_NAME_PENDING]: (state) => ({ ...state, fetching: true, error: false }),
  [GET_CATEGORY_NAME_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => ({ ...state, fetching: false, name: action.payload }),
  [GET_CATEGORY_NAME_FAILURE]: (state) => ({ ...state, fetching: false, error: true })
}, initialState);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using `bindActionCreators`.
But, still I don't understand why it never dispatched.

```javascript
(dispatch) => ({
    CategoryImgActions: bindActionCreators(categoryImgActions, dispatch)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe its the curly braces which are the problem, try this:

```js
  (dispatch) => ({
    fetchName: () => dispatch(CategoryImgActions.fetchName())
  })
```

If you are using curly braces you need to explicitly return:

```js
  (dispatch) => ({
    fetchName: () => {
      return dispatch(CategoryImgActions.fetchName());
    }
  })
```